# JMeter Change thread name or label in result file

Tags: jmeter, csv-file

I am using .csv file to read data input 
.csv file header:

```
ID | Design | Type | forname | secondName
1 | design1 | type1 | displayinResults | displayinResults2
```

Now, i am `using ID, Design and Type` as inputs and I would like to see `forname, secondName` in results.

Currently it is displayed as: `HTTP requests 1-1`, but i would like it to be displayed as `displayinResults displayinResults2` or `HTTP request displayinResults displayinResults2`

Lets say my label for http request is getWeatherinfo, 
I would like to see result getWeatherinfo + ${forname}
if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are using "**CSV Data Set Config**" Configuration element for providing input value to your script.

You can't change the **'Thread Name'** using the CSV file, as this is the functionality of listener (this is how it has been designed), but you can change the **'Label'** value shown in the results and **most of the times this Label is used for interpretation of Reports.** One more aspect of this functionality is, JMeter saves result file only in 1 common format for all listeners i.e. all the inbuilt listeners uses the same jtl file to display results in a different way and this Thread Name is taken from the "Name" property of Thread Group used in your testing and it continues in a series *(1-1, 1-2, 1-3... so on)*; where First digit is the Thread/user number and Second digit is the Request number for that user.

[image]

You can change it as a whole but it will not be picked from CSV file like you can make it **"Thread Group 1-1" to "User 1-1"**. As a standard practice you should change the label as this is what displayed in other listeners too. Like Label; Thread Name is not a common attribute for all listeners.

Comment: Ok, but this label(HTTP request) has different inputs. Is it possible to display lebel as: label + ${vorname} ?

Comment: Yes, you can change the label name and configure it to take value from CSV file. You need to the change the "Name" value of HTTP Request, do not change the "Path" value of HTTP Request.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Change HTTP request sampler name(label) to 
`${forname} ${secondName}`
where forname, secondName are .csv column headers